# How can I listen to an event inside a custom Readable stream in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, events, nodejs-stream, readable

This is my code :

```
class Counter extends Readable {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    _read () { 
        readStream.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            this.push(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
        readStream.on('end', () => {
            this.push(null);
        });
    }
}
```

I am getting this error and the processing also becomes very slow.

```
(node:18488) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory 
leak detected. 11 end listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() 
to increase limit (node:18488) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible 
EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 data listeners added. Use 
emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

This is my full code. Basically, I want to read a CSV. Convert it into JSON and write to a file. I want to do this operation using stream. I am using 'csv-parser' npm module

```
const  fs = require('fs');
var Readable = require('stream').Readable; 
const csv = require('csv-parser');


class Counter extends Readable {
   constructor() {
       super();
   }
   _read () { 
       readStream.on('data', (data) => {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
           this.push(JSON.stringify(data));
       });
       readStream.on('end', () => {
           this.push(null);
       });
   }
}
let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('tmp1');
let readStream = fs.createReadStream('tmp.csv').pipe(csv());
var counter = new Counter(); 
counter.pipe(writeStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried writing the 1.48GB csv file as json array into the file,it didn't give any errors  or warnings that you have mentioned.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser');

const server = http.createServer();

const writeStr = fs.createWriteStream('data.json', { flags: 'a' });
writeStr.write('[\n');
let sep = "";

server.on('request', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.method);

    fs.createReadStream('./Crimes_-_2001_to_present.csv').pipe(csv())
        .on('data', function (data) {
            writeStr.write(sep + JSON.stringify(data));
            if (!sep)
                sep = ",\n";
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            writeStr.write('\n]')
            console.log('DONE WRITING FILE');
            res.end();
        })
        .on('error', function (err) {
            consol.log(err);
        })
})
server.listen(8000);
```

FYI:the dataset is take from https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?res_format=CSV